# how to get the exact date of the last call in android?

Tags: java, android, date, call

I have my android app with Edittext , Button

Edittext : to allow the user to enter the number he wants .
Button : called "Call" to make the call .

and i want a way to get the exact date and time of the call after it finishes

my java code :
    public String string;
    public String number = null; //

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   Button CallButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

   CallButton.setOnClickListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       EditText txtcallnumber = null;
       txtcallnumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.callEdit);
    string = txtcallnumber.getText().toString();
       number = "tel:" +string ;
    Intent CallIntent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse(number));
    startActivity(CallIntent);



}
```

how can i do that ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your code successfully makes the phone call, then instead of using `startActivity`, use `startActivityForResult`. This tells your app to return to a particular part of your `Activity` once the phone call is completed. This part is the `onActivityResult` method.

Then, you will need to implement `onActivityResult` in your `Activity`.  If the `requestCode` that you used in `startActivityForResult` matches the `requestCode` argument, then get the current time from the system.

Comment: thanks a lot 
that made me understand new concepts 
helped me alot 
thanks again

Answer (score 0):

change startActivity to startActivityForResult

```
startActivityForResult(CallIntent, CALL_REQUEST_CODE);   // any integer value
```

get the result inside onActivityForResult

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {

            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            String dateTimeString = formatter.format(new Date(System
                    .currentTimeMillis()));

            Log.d("TIME", dateTimeString);

        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot 
there is a little error with me in that code 
but fine 
I tried another way to set the time to a textview 
thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Just as described in previous answer, you might start an activity for result then implement onActivityResult method like so:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            if(requestCode == DONE_CALL){


             }
        }
}
```

Inside of the method, you can do something like this to capture date and time:

```
Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
today.setToNow();
String formattedData = today.format("%F %H:%M");
```